# /usr/ucb/cc: language optional software package not installed

Tags: solaris

I need to compile a small C program (shared lib for a Perl module) on an old Solaris 8 (Sparc) server. Unfortunately the development tools are not installed and I'm getting:

`/usr/ucb/cc:  language optional software package not installed`

I've got access to Solaris resources on support.oracle.com but don't know what to look for. SolarisStudio 12.3 only seems to support Solaris 10+. Any idea where to get a native *C compiler* for Solaris 8?

Edit: The other question (supposed to be duplicate) doesn't really help. Anyway the **solution** is to install Sun Studio 11 - the last version that supports Solaris 8 and Solaris 9. Oracle patch 12685437 fwiw.

Comment: @Renan The other question does not cover the version problem, does it?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the GNU compiler toolchain as Solaris installable package from http://www.sunfreeware.com/. It's not native in that it's not a Sun-provided compiler (or Oracle-provided nowadays), but it is native in that the package was compiled and built on Solaris systems.

Comment: I tried gcc from OpenCSW, struggled with the build (gcc options are different from Sun cc ones) and the compiled module didn't work with the original Sun Perl (missing symbols). May be fine for compiling GNU programs but not for old Solaris ones :(

Comment: The missing symbols error is unlikely to be related to the compiler used, but rather to the module being compiled. I'm not sure you're going to be able to find an actual Sun-provided compiler for this system any longer - and even if you do, you may not be able to get a license for it that will let it work.